# Error message while trying to update Homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to update Homebrew on my computer, but when I type in 'brew update' I get this error message:

```
Error: undefined method `close!' for nil:NilClass
Please report this bug:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:129:in `ensure in atomic_write'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:129:in `atomic_write'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/untap.rb:42:in `unlink_tap_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.rb:24:in `update'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:134:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas as to why this is? How can I fix this and have Homebrew run normally on my computer? 
Thanks!

Comment: try `brew doctor` first and then `brew cleanup` just to ensure your home-brew is working and not carrying around any junk.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I just tried "brew cleanup" and got this error messageError: Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/bin/c_rehash

Comment: I guess fixing the permissions on that folder will fix that then.